# How to insert a custom label in between two fields in newform.aspx?

Tags: text

I have a form with many fields in it. I want to group 4-5 fields so that they can fall below the custom label. How to create this? I have very limited knowledge of coding.

I want to have custom labels like shown in the figure:

http://i45.tinypic.com/33agm0y.png

I picked up a coding from net and inserted it but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First, create your webusercontrol

WebUserControl1.ascx

This code is

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebUserControl1" %>
<asp:Label ID="label" runat="server" >
        </asp:Label>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
```

Add this code behind for your usercontrol

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label.Text = MyProperty;
        }
    }
}
```

Secondly create your aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Register TagName="test" TagPrefix="uc" Src="~/WebUserControl1.ascx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

     <uc:test id="uc1" runat="server" MyProperty="Texte1"></uc:test>
     <uc:test id="uc2" runat="server" MyProperty="Texte2"></uc:test>
     <uc:test id="uc3" runat="server" MyProperty="Texte3"></uc:test>
     <uc:test id="uc4" runat="server" MyProperty="Texte4"></uc:test>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please simpplify a bit/... its going above my head

Comment: http://moblog.bradleyit.com/2009/04/creating-sections-in-sharepoint-forms.html     please take a look and tell me how to implement it

Comment: 1. Because you want create generic control, then with .net you can create  a user control, then i created user control, this control have two part : aspx and aspx.cs, and this control must be injected in your page , then i create page with aspx extension, and i inject usercontrol, try with the code

Comment: i already have a page..can i add label to it or i have to start from the begining?

Comment: <asp:label id="lbl" runat="server" Text="your text"/>

Comment: where do i insert his? will this line do my job?